# Which sentence is better in grammar?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is better? Is there any error in the sentence?

> 1.*The senator **urged for it to be taken** the fact that my father is a liar.*
> 2.*The senator **urged it to be taken** the fact that my father is a liar.*

And please tell me if there is any other expression for that sentence?

Answer (score 2):

If you look up **urge** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/urge), you will see various possible usages.

When **urge** has an object, the object is the person or group that you are trying to persuade, for example:

> The managers urged **the union leaders** to reconsider the strike.

This means that usage of **urge** in the second sentence is incorrect, because the object in the second sentence is **it**, not the people.

It is possible to use **for** followed by a noun phrase:

> The lawyer urged **for** leniency for his clients.

The first sentence is therefore valid up until **for**. There is, however a problem with the rest of the sentence: you can't say "taken the fact that". You can easily fix this by saying "taken **as** fact that".

The sentence is still difficult because the latter part is in passive voice. It would read better if you used active voice- "take it as fact", which aligns closely with the stock phrase "[take it as read](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-as-read?q=take%20%20sth%20%20as%20read)". This would make it more readable, and also make the preposition unnecessary.

This would suggest both that the senator was trying to persuade people that your father was a liar, and **also** that he didn't want them to check whether or not it was true.

Note that one of the uses of [present simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-simple) is to talk about "something that is always true"... unless you believe that your father was, and still is, a liar, it might be better to use simple past **was** rather than simple present **is**.

> The senator urged [whoever] to take it as fact that my father was a liar.
> The senator urged to take it as fact that my father was a liar.